# Delete cell content using itextsharp pdf api

Tags: c#, wpf, itext

Got a question on table formatting when using iText7 for .Net . I want to create a table with data pulled from a database, ie, populating the table dynamically. I need the table not to have any borders.

I've tried using `myTable.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;` to no avail. So, I resorted to using cells, instead. Using `cell.Border = 0;` works just fine. However, when I add content to the cell, using `cell.AddElement`, it keeps adding content to the cell, but not overwriting it. This is a problem for dynamic table creation.

My question is whether there is a way to clear the contents of a cell (like `cell.Delete()` or so).
I know there is no obvious method under `cell`, but maybe there is a hack some of you know about. So, how can I delete the contents of a table cell using iText7 for .Net?

Comment: Are you sure you are using iText7? Since the namespace is no longer iTextSharp, and tables don't have DefaultCell anymore.
There's no delete content option on BlockElement (which cell and table inherited from), since it's expected that you resolve the contents of a cell before it gets added to a table. Are you modifying a cell after adding it?

Comment: Ralf is definitely not using iText 7. Dear Ralf, please rephrase your question, because currently it is not clear which version of iText you're using.

Comment: The version I'm using is 5.5.9.0. Sorry for the misinfo. And, yes, I'm modifying a cell after I add it. I instantiate a cell and it gets updated (actually, added on to)  in a loop of data from a table.